# Mysql intersection based on single field

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with php and mysql. I have 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`emails` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`phones` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`history` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`insert_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=259 ;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `emails`, `phones`, `history`, `insert_date`)
VALUES
(118, 'PLEASE SET',  'addr@yahoo.com', 'None','2015-01-13'),
(237, 'PLEASE SET', 'addr@yahoo.com', 'gomez', '2015-01-11');
```

and

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable2` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`history` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=259 ;

INSERT INTO `mytable2` (`id`, `history`)
VALUES
(1, 'bob',),
(2 , 'gomez');
```

After making a selection :

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable1`
WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

I want to find the subset of  records in mytable2 that have a history field that match the history fields selected with the above query. This is basically an intersection based on the history field. I'm not sure how to code this in mysql, especially since 'intersect' does not exist.

Comment: why not simply JOIN matching field like history from two table with your desired condtion in WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for this job:

```
SELECT 
  m1.* 
FROM
  mytable m1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 m2 
    ON m1.history = m2.history
```

returns:

```
id  emails      phones          history insert_date
237 PLEASE SET  addr@yahoo.com  gomez   2015-01-11
```

The query in your question would look like this:

```
SELECT 
  m1.* 
FROM
  mytable m1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 m2 
    ON m1.history = m2.history 
WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

And it correctly returns nothing because the only qualifying record has a date older than 3 days.

Here is an incredibly useful infographic relating set operations to SQL functions

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a great answer! what I actually want is the records in table B after the inner join. To do that I assume Iwould just reverse m1 and m2?

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, to get intersect data from two tables you can use **joins**

Have a look at these links:

[MySQL Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

[MySQL Joins Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Try simple join common field like `history` from two tables with **INNER JOIN** and Add **WHERE** condition for other criteria.for more information see Mysql [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT 
  m1.* 
FROM
`mytable1` m1 
INNER JOIN `mytable2` m2 
    ON m1.history = m2.history
WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Join Mysql

```
SELECT  tbl1.* FROM `mytable` tbl1 INNER JOIN `mytable2` tbl2 ON 
tbl1.history = tbl2.history WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```