# How to apply where cause in mysql join query to different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql statement based on [Mysql intersection based on single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997211/mysql-intersection-based-on-single-field):

```
SELECT 
  m1.* 
FROM
  mytable m1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 m2 
    ON m1.history = m2.history 
WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Does the where clause applies to the first table. How do you apply the where clause to the second table or the first table?

edit: what I am actually trying to do is to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable1`
WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

and then get the inner joined records of mytable2 (m2) :

```
ON m1.history = m2.history
```

My original query may be correct but I'm not sure.

This made me start thinking: What if I wanted to apply conditions to the join of either or both tables. I'm not sure how to build that query.

Comment: You would include columns from both tables.  Perhaps you should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Or, at least a question the query is supposed to answer.

Comment: You can select both table columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql will handle that for you, you can put columns from either table in the where clause.  Think of the join as producing a new table with columns from both tables in it, then the where clause applies that that result set.  If you have the same columns in both tables you just need to provide the name of the table or alias in your case to get the column.  In fact your query won't compile if that is the case unless you do so:

```
SELECT 
  m1.* 
FROM
  mytable m1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 m2 
    ON m1.history = m2.history 
WHERE m2.`insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks for spelling this out for me Jason, especially "Think of the join as producing a new table with columns from both tables in it". That helps me make sense of this. - Bill

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can add the condition to either the ON clause or the WHERE clause. However, per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the ON conditions (ideally) are used to describe how the tables should be joined while the WHERE conditions are for everything else. I'm still fairly new to MySQL, though, so I could be missing something.

e.g.,

```
SELECT 
  m1.* 
FROM
  mytable m1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 m2 
    ON m1.history = m2.history 
WHERE 
    `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
    AND
    m2.id > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any columns in where clause from tables in that SQL Statement. Either in WHERE Clause with USING AND or ON Clause in INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT m1.* 
FROM mytable m1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 m2 ON m1.history = m2.history 
             AND m2.YourColumnnameHereFromSecondTable = anyvalue <<<----- HERE
WHERE m1.insert_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
      AND m2.YourColumnnameHereFromSecondTable = anyvalue        <<<----- HERE
```

REFER [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php) and [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm), [HERE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

Comment: The way you've done this is very helpful, but borrowing from your terminology, how would you integrate: "AND m1.YourColumnnameHereFromFirstTable = anyvalue" ?